# What the gloves without the part of the fingers called in English?

Tags: image-identification

What the gloves without the part of the fingers called in English?

I know 2 types:

- Gloves **without** the part that covering the fingers (pic.1)
- Gloves **with half** covering of the fingers. (pic. 2)
  [image: pic.1]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first kind are just called *fingerless gloves*.

For example, in an advertisement,

[image]

The second kind are called *cuffs*, although cuffs do not always have the part that wraps around the thumb. More usually they're a simple tube around the wrist. This dates to when cuffs were made separate from shirts so that they could be laundered more frequently than the rest of the shirt. For example, on a knitting website:

[image]

Comment: If you want to be certain that you are referring to the version with just the thumb hole, you would probably call them wristlets, wrist-warmers or wristers.